# Modifying content from new dictionary also modifies the parent dictionary data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

As I have a requirement to add similar objects into the array, I have created new dictionary in such a way.

```
NSMutableDictionary* existingStepDict = [[[arrayForSteps objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy] autorelease];
[arrayForSteps addObject:existingStepDict];
[existingStepDict release];
```

Now, what happens here is that later when I change something in any one of the dictionary, the other one also gets updated. I require both these dictionaries to behave independently.

For that I went through Deep-copy of dictionaries whose code is like this.

```
   NSMutableDictionary* existingStepDict = [[[arrayForSteps objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy] autorelease];

   NSMutableDictionary* destination = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];

   NSDictionary *deepCopy = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:existingStepDict copyItems: YES];
   if (deepCopy) {
        [destination addEntriesFromDictionary: deepCopy];
        [deepCopy release];
   }
   //add Properties array to Steps Dictionary
   [arrayForSteps addObject:destination];
```

But this too didn't reflect the difference. I know I am making some minor mistake here. 
But could some one help me getting my result?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I edit my previous answer to include another option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easy way to get a **full** deepcopy of an NSDictionary o NSArray using the NSCoding (serialization) protocol.

```
- (id) deepCopy:(id)mutableObject
{
    NSData *buffer = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:mutableObject];
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: buffer];
}
```

In this way you can duplicate any object plus all the obects it contains in a single step.

Answer (score 1):

when I need a mutable deep copy of a `NSDictionary` I create a Category with this method:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)mutableDeepCopy
{
    NSMutableDictionary *returnDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[self count]];
    NSArray *keys = [self allKeys];

    for (id key in keys) {
        id oneValue = [self valueForKey:key];
        id oneCopy = nil;
        if ([oneValue respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableDeepCopy)]) {
            oneCopy = [oneValue mutableDeepCopy];
        } else if ([oneValue respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopy)]) {
            oneCopy = [oneValue mutableCopy];
        }
        if (oneCopy == nil) {
            oneCopy = [oneValue copy];
        }

        [returnDict setValue:oneCopy forKey:key];
    }

    return returnDict;
}
```

**EDIT**
and searching the web I found this, I haven't tested

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableCopy = (NSMutableDictionary *)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDictionaryRef)originalDictionary, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I tried `mutableDeepCopy` option and it didnt work out. But then Malvagio's answer works perfectly!